# TeamCity fails deploying to Artifactory - reports "Expected a folder but found a file"

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, artifactory

I have a Maven build that was recently working and properly deploying, and now it fails to deploy. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed in the build settings nor the pom.xml. *(I did a diff on the pom from the successful and failing folders and they are identical; assuming the folder hasn't been updated.)*

The balance of the Maven builds are able to deploy. I'm using the same template for all projects, and the same settings.xml file as well.

The build completes successfully, and then things get weird. I've looked at the logs from both builds in TeamCity and the command seems the same, other than the failure (which quits at that point).

### Things that I've noticed:

1. The failing log message in Artifactory issues a `mkdir` command,
2. then later warns about expecting a directory but found a file,
3. which searching for that phrase, I found the exception class. [`FolderExpectedException`](http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/trunk/base/api/src/main/java/org/artifactory/api/repo/exception/FolderExpectedException.java) for Artifactory.
4. The log in TeamCity looks the same up until the failure.
5. Other Maven builds (using same build template & settings.xml file) successfully deploy.
6. I ran diff against the succeeding and failing poms and there were no differences.
7. Currently, I do not have the successful log from Artifactory; I'm going to dig on the machine though and see if I can find older logs.
8. In both work directories on the build agents (successful & not), the jar is at `target/mylib.jar`
9. Max unique snapshots are set to 0, so I don't think this is related to [this older bug.](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-3914)
10. If I move the snapshots out of libs-snapshot-local to a blacklisted repository and tried deploying again... it will create the `5-6-0-SNAPSHOT` root folder, but then it creates empty subfolders named the same as the jar and pom! But the artifact in TeamCity at target/mylib.jar is most definitely a jar file.
11. TeamCity 8.0.4 build 27616; Artifactory 3.0.1 rev 30008
12. TeamCity was recently upgraded from 8.0.2, and the deployment was working at that point. I have not tried rolling it back, but other builds based on the same build template are successfully deploying, so I do not think that's it, but that may be the next thing to check.
13. Artifact paths (from general settings) is: `**/*.jar`
14. The account that this is run under is a domain account and is not locked out. It has full control of the TeamCity Build Agent directories on each build machine.

### Questions:

1. What else can I look for?
2. Is there something I can try changing?
3. Is there anything I can do to export everything TeamCity saw on the successful build versus the failing build now?

*TeamCity log - successful*

```
[Step 1/1] Publishing artifacts  
[Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish:  
    [E:\TCBuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.tc-maven-bi\maven-build-info.xml.gz  
    => .teamcity]  
[Publishing artifacts] Sending  
    E:/TCBuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/.tc-maven-bi/maven-build-info.xml.gz  
[Step 1/1] Deploying artifacts to http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory  
[Step 1/1] Deploying artifact:  
    http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/  
    com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  
[11:07:24][Step 1/1] Deploying artifact:  
    http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/  
    com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom  
[11:07:27][Step 1/1] Deploying build info ...  
[11:07:27][Step 1/1] Deploying build info to:  
    http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory/api/build
```

*TeamCity log - failure*

```
[Step 1/1] Publishing artifacts  
[Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: 
    [E:\TCBuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.tc-maven-bi\maven-build-info.xml.gz => 
    .teamcity]  
[Publishing artifacts] Sending 
    E:/TCBuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/.tc-maven-bi/maven-build-info.xml.gz  
[Step 1/1] Deploying artifacts to http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory  
[Step 1/1] Deploying artifact: 
    http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/
    com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  
[Step 1/1] Error deploying artifact: 
    E:\TCBuildAgent\work\2e99f45d5745c8fa\target\mylib.jar. Skipping 
    deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info.
```

*Artifactory log - failure - **note the `mkdir -p` command on the jar***

```
2013-10-08 18:00:23,718 [http-bio-8081-exec-1424] [INFO ]  
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:263) - MKDir request to  
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  
2013-10-08 18:00:23,734 [http-bio-8081-exec-1424] [WARN ]  
    (o.a.s.f.l.SessionLockEntry:111) - Mutable item  
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  
    has local modifications that will be discarded.  
2013-10-08 18:00:23,734 [http-bio-8081-exec-1424] [ERROR]  
    (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter :206) - Sending HTTP error code 500: Expected a folder  
    but found a file, at:  
    libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  
2013-10-08 18:00:23,734 [http-bio-8081-exec-1425] [INFO ]  
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:263) - MKDir request to  
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  
2013-10-08 18:00:23,749 [http-bio-8081-exec-1425] [WARN ]  
    (o.a.s.f.l.SessionLockEntry:111) - Mutable item  
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  
    has local modifications that will be discarded.  
2013-10-08 18:00:23,749 [http-bio-8081-exec-1425] [ERROR]  
    (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter :206) - Sending HTTP error code 500: Expected a folder  
    but found a file, at:  
    libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

*The relevant pom.xml entries %<-- snip:*

```
<groupId>com.company.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
<version>5.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>mylib</name>

<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy.MM.dd:HH.mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <main.package>com.company.myapp</main.package>
    <build.time>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.time>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ciassets</id>
        <name>ciassets-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://myserver.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

*The Artifactory logfile when it creates the directories instead of the poms:*

```
2013-10-08 19:12:19,198 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:263) - MKDir request to 
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
2013-10-08 19:12:19,214 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:269) - Directory 
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' 
    was created successfully.
2013-10-08 19:12:19,448 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:263) - MKDir request to 
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'
2013-10-08 19:12:19,464 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:269) - Directory 
    'libs-snapshot-local:com/company/myapp/mylib/5.6.0-SNAPSHOT/mylib-5.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom' 
    was created successfully.
2013-10-08 19:12:19,682 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:280) - Adding build 
    'Java Stack :: My App - branch 5.6.0/ #9_412'
2013-10-08 19:12:19,792 [http-bio-8081-exec-1454] [INFO ] 
    (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:296) - Added build 
    'Java Stack :: My App - branch 5.6.0/ #9_412'
```

Comment: I would try checking directory/user permissions for the failing build.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked this out, but it doesn't appear to be a permissions problem. I use the same build template for all Maven builds, and the same user is used for each. That user is a domain user and a member of the Administrators group on each build agent, and I have verified it is not locked out; plus, it still works on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the TeamCity build configuration. My guess is it was corrupted during the update from 8.0.2 to 8.0.4, but I'm not 100% sure. *I'm submitting a bug to them.*

The way I determined this is a problem with that config:

1. Created a new config from the Maven build template (same template the failing is based off of)
2. Set the new config with the same build parameters as the corrupted one
3. Fired off a build against the new config, succeeded.
4. Verified multiple times that the build parameters are identical.

As an interesting aside, I made a backup of these, then copied them to a new project in TeamCity. When I did that, they both succeeded, including the one that was a copy of the one that was failing in the main project.

In the original project, it seems to be stuck on an older revision as well. Hopefully they can shed some light on why it's failing (and maybe provide a better error message in the future), but, I was able to get around it.

Comment: I cannot mark this as resolved for 6 hours. I will mark it resolved tomorrow.